# Custom Realtime Data in PowerBI Dashboards

Tags: powerbi

I am new to the powerbi platform and have a challenge of scoping/converting an old dashboard solution to powerbi.

The old dashboard solution is custom made and refreshes data every minute.

Powerbi lists its refresh rate for 8 times a day for Pro and 48times a day on Enterprice. Does that means there is no option to provide the same realtime (1min) updates in a dashboard using powerbi?

Can you embed iframes or anything in a powerbi dashboard?
How can you do a realtime graph in powerbi if it only refreshes 8 times a day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refreshing data 8/48 times a day is applicable when you **import** data in Power BI dataset. But if you want "more recent" data, you can connect to your data source using [DirectQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-use-directquery) mode. DirectQuery sends queries to your data source when rendering the report. If you apply a filter, the database will get a new query, and so on. Not every data source supports DirectQuery, e.g. you can't use it for flat files (obviously). You may want to take a look at [Data refresh in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/refresh-data) article.

For embedding iframes in Power BI report you can use [HTML Viewer](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104381214) custom visual.

By default when using DirectQuery mode, tiles pinned to a dashboard refresh automatically hourly ([Datasets in DirectQuery/LiveConnect mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/refresh-data#datasets-in-directqueryliveconnect-mode)), but you can reduce this time down to 15 minutes:

> A tile is a report visual pinned to a dashboard, and dashboard tile refreshes happen **about every hour** so that the tiles show recent results. **You can change the schedule** in the dataset settings, as in the screenshot below, or force a dashboard update manually by using the Refresh Now option.

However if you want to display real-time data in Power BI dashboard, it will be better to use push or streaming datasets. With push datasets you can programatically [push data to the dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/walkthrough-push-data) and the data will be stored and you can use them in reports. Streaming datasets are similar to push, but they will keep only the last hour of data pushed to them and can't be used in report, only pinned to a dashboard. There are also other options, like using [PubNub](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/microsoft-power-bi-integrates-pubnub-for-realtime-data-visualization/) or [Microsoft Flow](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/MBAS-Gallery/Microsoft-Flow-and-Power-BI-Build-a-real-time-dashboard-in-20/td-p/726033). For more information also take a look at [Real-time streaming in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-real-time-streaming).